# Materialized View REFRESH ON COMMIT blocked sessions

Tags: oracle, session, commit, materialized-views

I created a materialized view in Oracle 19c with REFRESH FAST ON COMMIT as the following:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW LOG ON MY_TABLE
  WITH SEQUENCE, ROWID(ID, COLUMN1, COLUMN2, COLUMN3)
  INCLUDING NEW VALUES;

CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW MV_MYVIEW
  BUILD IMMEDIATE 
  REFRESH FAST ON COMMIT  
  DISABLE QUERY REWRITE
  AS        
     SELECT COLUMN1, COLUMN2, count(*) AS COLUMN4
      FROM MY_TABLE
      WHERE COLUMN3 IS NULL
      GROUP BY COLUMN1, COLUMN2;
```

Fast refresh seems to work fine with the explain:

```
BEGIN
 DBMS_MVIEW.EXPLAIN_MVIEW ('MV_MYVIEW');
END;

SELECT *
FROM MV_CAPABILITIES_TABLE
where MVNAME = 'MV_MYVIEW'
ORDER BY seq;
```

[image: mv capabilities]

The problem is that during some performance tests writing a lot in the main table MY_TABLE, blocked sessions increased drastically.
[image]

Is this something normal with MV on COMMIT? The main table MY_TABLE is not so big (528729 rows) and the query is fast.

[image: explain plan]

Once the blocking sessions gone, I tried to DROP the MV but it's hanging for a looong time with locking sessions and I cannot delete it. I tried to kill the sessions, truncate the table, drop the logs, change the refresh to on demand ... nothing works
[image]

Comment: why are you using a combination of sequence/rowid for the mview log ? Is there any update scenario where you need that combination for the log ??

Comment: Try to create an Index for the column used in group by `COLUMN1, COLUMN2` in the materialized view and check again. and also `ON DEMAND` is good option here.

Comment: You may want to try to find out precisely what commands are blocking and what are being blocked. You can investigate blockers starting with a simple query like this: `select * from gv$session where blocking_session is not null;`